# HTML : get special character without formating

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have a select, following is console output.

```
> select.options[select.selectedIndex]
  <option value=​"49">​books & stationary​</option>​
> select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  "books &amp; stationary"
```

When I use innerHTML call it formats the value and replaces `&` with `&amp;` how I can I get unformatted value?

Comment: Replaces "&" with "&"? or you meant replaces "&" with "&amp"?

Comment: use `decodeURIComponent(select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML)`

Comment: @Prabhuram didn't work

Comment: @Prabhuram: `decodeURIComponent` is for URI decoding (as the name says), not for HTML entity decoding. There is no ready-made function for that - the best you can do is either wing it with custom `replace`, or make a HTML element and read its `textContent`.

Comment: Use `select.options[select.selectedIndex].text`

Answer (score 2):

In asking for `innerHTML`, you're asking for HTML. In HTML, the `&` character is special, and it is technically an error to write `books & stationery` - it should say `books &amp; stationery`. The browser is smart enough to recognise what you mean when it is not ambiguous, and correct it. Thus when you ask for HTML back, you're getting the corrected value.

If you want the *text*, that is another matter. Use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`.

If you already *got* the HTML and want to strip HTML markup and get text from it, you can do this:

```
function strip_html_to_text(html) {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = html;
  return el.textContent;
}
```

Comment: Writing `books & stationery` is not an error, except in XHTML. And the `&` is stored as such in the DOM. It is the serialization, caused by the reference to `innerHTML`, that converts it to `&amp;`.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be rather simpler. Text function call gives the text I was looking for

> select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;

```
output:  books & stationary
```

Comment: This is the best answer, since the `text` property is supported by all browsers. (The `textContent` property lacks support in IE 8 and older.)

Answer (score 1):

Use replace together with textContent instead of innerHTML:

```
select.options[select.selectedIndex].textContent.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get only text of selected option. You can use `.textContent` instead of using `.innerHTML`.

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/JkSmj/2/)

[.textContent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp)